# How is his name "Chewbacca"?

Tags: star-wars, languages, names

Chewbacca (Chewie to his friends) is the Wookiee in the original *Star Wars* trilogy.  We know his name because people other than he say his name.  Whenever he speaks, it's in growls and other noises, he can't verbalize Basic like the humans and C-3P0 can.  But, he also can't enunciate the name 'Chewbacca'.  Other Wookiees have the same issue, they have names that they obviously couldn't pronounce.

How does Chewbacca have that name, when he himself cannot pronounce it?

Comment: I would argue that he pronounces it correctly, and we mispronounce it.

Comment: http://www.filmsmarts.com/movies/starwars/c_chewbacca.html

Comment: Or maybe it's the Basic translation of whatever his name is in http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Shyriiwook

Comment: @BrendanHughes Y'know, your link provides an answer...  It is indeed a translation, but doesn't appear to be of his original name.  (Or if it is, it seems a rather large/intentional coincidence with him and Solo)

Comment: It's just a matter of accent. Just because you can't understand it, it doesn't mean he can't speak the word.

Comment: If only Wookies were somehow literate and could somehow communicate using the written word so they could just spell these things.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The canon comic *Chewbacca* shows that he does not pronounce his name as "Chewbacca."

> Zarro: Do you have a name?
>
> Chewbacca: YRRAANNH!
>
> Zarro: I don't... know how to say that.

This is [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Shyriiwook)'s explanation for the apparent descrepancy. It makes sense to me.

> The unique shape of the Wookiee throat made Shyriiwook a very difficult, even impossible language to speak for most non-Wookiees; presumably the word Shyriiwook itself, as well as other Wookiee words or names, were transliterations of the original Wookiee sounds into a form more easily pronounced by others.

Comment: I honestly don't see how this answers the question.   It doesn't explain how *YRRAANNH* transliterates to *Chewbacca*, which are just to conspicuously different to ignore and just chalk up to 'transliteration'.

Comment: @ThePopMachine 'YRRAANNH' is probably as close to 'Chewbacca' as he can get. Considering how almost every noise he makes sounds nearly identical, I'm sure there are a lot more distinctive sounds in that growl to his ears than ours. Sort of like how Chinese sounds like indistinguishable, nonsensical yelling to a lot of English speakers.

Comment: @DCShannon: your describing Chinese as yelling aside, the point is that there are certain basic features to sounds that don't just disappear in transliteration just because *you* can't distinguish or pronounce some of their features.   In particular, it doesn't make any sense to transliterate one sound as a completely different number of syllables.    That's why the explanation isn't convincing.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Chew => YRR, ba => AA, ca => NNH. The mouth movements aren't that different. If you're not convinced, then you're not convinced, but it seems close enough to me.

Comment: @DCShannon, not sure if kidding or not.

Comment: @ThePopMachine That was supposed to be my last comment on the issue, but to clarify: completely serious. Chewbacca does not have a human mouth. It is entirely believable that those sounds are his analogue of 'Chewbacca'.

Comment: @ThePopMachine No, it's YRRAARRRGHH. You're supposed to pronounce it at the *back* of the throat. *No, in surprise and alarm!* -You mean a sort of a "Ah!" -Yes, that's right. *"He's tearing off my arms! YRRAHH!"*

Comment: A claim by Wookieepedia is not a canon source.   But, recent revelations show [that *Chewbacca* is derived directly from the Shyriiwook](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/188955/3823), not just a name created by others.    So this answer is essentially correct, but unsourced.

Comment: Maybe the frequencies that make up the syllables 'Chew' 'ba' 'cca' are in a frequency outside of human hearing. Compare the 'Laurel'-'Yanny' debate. I first heard 'Laurel', but when you adjust the frequencies down you find that people with better hearing are hearing higher frequencies that make it 'Yanny'. That's proof that at least one hard consonant - 'n' - can be lost entirely because of bad hearing.
Presumably the people who first transliterated Shyriiwook put the sounds through audio software before transliterating. They'd have to, or all the complexity in the language would be lost.

Answer (score 24):

This is explained in the Star Wars RPG sourcebook "[Galactic Campaign Guide](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Galactic_Campaign_Guide)".

> *"Because names in the Wookiee language of Shyriiwook can't be
>   pronounced by most species, **the standard convention for other species
>   is to translate the Wookiee name into a series of roughly similar
>   phonics.** Wookiees are comfortable with this practice since they
>   understand Basic enough to recognise Basic versions of their names,
>   and see no reason to insist that other species hurt themselves for the
>   sake of accurate pronunciation."*

Obviously it's worth noting that this book is no longer considered canon, but it's about as good an explanation as any.

Comment: Recent revelations show [that *Chewbacca* is derived directly from the Shyriiwook](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/188955/3823), not just a name created by others.   So this answer is pretty much canon.

Answer (score 15):

I feel like this addition is necessary after the release of *Solo: A Star Wars Story*.

It is established that Han knows some Shyriiwook, and he actually speaks some while Han and Chewie are in the cage together.   Later, we have Han asking Chewie his name.

> HAN: So what's your name, anyway? 
>   CHEWIE:  [Wookiee growling]  
>   HAN: Chewbacca? (CHUCKLES) All right, well, you're gonna need a nickname, 'cause I ain't saying that every time. 
>   CHEWIE: [Growls]

Read more: https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=solo-a-star-wars-story
This is actually quite indicative, since *Chewbacca* is a proper noun, they've clearly never met before, and Chewbacca is not previously known to Han.

So this demonstrates that however it is that the Basic transliteration (probably better say *transphonetization*) works, there is some sort of mapping between the original Shyriiwook phonology and Basic phonology.   I.e. One can hear a word in the original Shyriiwook and do a standard mapping into this alternate pronunciation for the rest of the Galaxy to employ.

So, **that's** how it is that his name is *Chewbacca*.

Answer (score 14):

Maybe Chewbacca is his name used by the "human" characters in Star Wars.

It is quite common for ethnic groups and places to have different names in different languages.  Many of those names are completely different from the name used by the inhabitants.

And many people are given nicknames by foreigners in their own languages.

For example, General George Crook was called  *Nantan Lupan* or "Gray Wolf Chief" by the Apaches, who of course did not call themselves Apaches but *Inde*, which by coincidence sounds a lot like *Indio*, the Spanish word for Indian.

If Wookiees can't pronounce their names that are heard or read in Star Wars, obviously those must be outsider names given them by non-Wookiees.

Comment: A good EU example of this is how the Mon Cal call their planet "Dac" but other species call it something like Mon Calamari.

Comment: Recent revelations show [that *Chewbacca* is derived directly from the Shyriiwook](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/188955/3823), not just a name created by others.