# What was Chewie's last name? Does he even have one?

Tags: star-wars, names, chewbacca

I have never seen the new *Solo* movie, so this may be a dumb question, but really, *what is Chewbacca's last name, if he has one?* Han just calls him Chewie,  Chewbacca, or thing's like that, and never (as far as I remember) mention's his last name. I have wondered this for a while, and would be grateful for a reliable, canon answer (not based on a comic or that Star Wars Christmas special or something similar) if that is possible.

Comment: Chewbacca Rahhggaahh Urughaghhh ! How could you miss it?!

Comment: [Wookiepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Chewbacca's_family) has an entry for Chewbacca's family and for Wookies in general, and every Wookie appears to just have one name.  It lists his father as Attichitcuk and his son as Lumpawaroo, so it doesn't appear to be a conjunction of a given name and a family name.  Someone may have a more definitive answer than Wookiepedia though.

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105222/how-is-his-name-chewbacca

Comment: According to Joonas Suotamo (Chewbacca actor in the *Solo* film), [it's "Jones"](https://ew.com/movies/2018/05/25/solo-star-wars-chewbacca-last-name-joonas-suotamo/)

Comment: Alternately, [it's "Stein"](https://www.therpf.com/forums/threads/chewbaccas-last-name-revealed.279609/)

Comment: No mention in _Alien Archive_ or _Solo: The Official Guide_, _Revenge of the Sith: The Visual Dictionary_, or _galactic Phrase Book & Travel Guide_. Someone who has one of the RPG sourcebooks might check there - if there's a section on Wookiee character creation, it might explicitly describe their name structure.

Comment: Relevant: [Falsehoods SFF.SE Members Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Comment: I remember a jingle for an candy bar which when something like: "Chewy, chewy caramel, Nestle's hundred thousand dollar bar" (I never did understand the price reference) and can't help imagining putting Chewbacca into the jingle.  So maybe his name is actually Chewy Bacca.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to *[The Star Wars 7](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Star_Wars_7)*, the adaptation of Lucas's original shooting script, [Chewbacca is part of the Sawa Tribe](https://aminoapps.com/c/star-wars/page/item/chewbaccas-family/nKFK_I8voZpVWWaxzZg5qEpjoDnq7a), later renamed to "the Great Kaapauku tribe".

> [In] the Legends book titled "The Star Wars 7", Chewbacca and his family are identified as the "Sawa Tribe" among other clans on Kashyyyk. The name means that they are one of the most powerful tribes on the planet, with the father being the prince and his name is "Auzituck" in the book. In the sequel to the book, called "The Star Wars 8", the family has a new alias under "the Great Kaapauku tribe"

Admittedly, this is almost certainly no longer the official continuity.

Comment: So I can just call him "Chewbacca of the Sawa Tribe", and that counts as a last name?

Comment: The purpose of surnames has historically been to tie yourself to a larger group, such as a family, such as the Arabic [*nisbah*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_name#Nisbah), "al-Farsī" meaning "of the Persians".

Comment: Yes, the first thing I thought of when I read this answer was Aragorn, son of Arathorn, and I'm still not *totally* sure he has a last name either.

Comment: That said, as far as I know, Chewie has not identified himself using that name, and not every culture uses surnames as part of the name, so his (transliterated) full name may simply be "Chewbacca".

Comment: :) Or it's just nicknames, like how one of my college friends dated both "Airforce Ed" and "Asshole Ed" and just about everyone in the engineering program for our years knew exactly which Ed was which. :-D Admittedly, "Airforce Ed" changed to "Stalker Ed" by his Senior year due to a few incidents that led to a restraining order...

Comment: @CaptainKirk “You can call him anything you like, he won’t come anyway.”

Comment: `z` and `t` just don't seem like plausible consonants for a Wookie ("Auzituck")

Comment: Surnames are not universal. The use of surnames dates back to antiquity in China, but is less than a thousand years old in Western culture. In Indonesia, most people do not have surnames; for instance, Sukarno and Suharto are complete names.

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: @FuzzyBoots, as I understand it, the purpose of surnames is tax. The taxman  more than anyone else needed a way of distinguishing  the various Johns in a town from each other.

Comment: Hmm every time I've seen his father brought up it's been Attichituk or some similar spelling